# How to fix ModuleNotFoundError "while upgrading selenium from 3.13.1 to 4.1.0"

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement import FirefoxWebElement as WebElement

E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement'

This particular import was available in selenium 3.13.1 but not available in 4.1.0

How to replace this import in selenium 4.1.0

Comment: works perfectly fine. `windows10`, `vscode`...   have you uninstalled and reinstalled selenium with `pip install webdriver-manager` ?  what have you tried ?

Comment: I am running on windows10, Pycharm...yes I tried uninstall and reinstall. looks like this import isn't available in 4.1.0 version. I am looking for the replacement for this import.   Thank you.

Comment: i got it working updated from 3-> 4 (for chrome) quite quickly...